# order a vector of points based on another vector

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, vector, stl-algorithm

I am working on a C++ application.

I have 2 vectors of points

```
vector<Point2f> vectorAll;
vector<Point2f> vectorSpecial;
```

Point2f is defined `typedef Point_<float> Point2f;`

vectorAll has 1000 point while vectorSpecial has 10 points.

**First Step:**

I need to order the points in vectorSpecial depending on their order in vectorAll.
So something like this:

```
For each Point in vectorSpecial
    Get The Order Of that point in the vectorAll
    Insert it in the correct order in a new vector
```

I can do a double loop and save the indexes. and then order the points based on their indexes. However this method is taking too long when we have lots of points (for example 10000 points in vectorAll and 1000 points in vectorSpecial so that's ten million iteration)

What are better methods of doing that?

**Second Step:**

Some points in vectorSpecial might not be available in vectorAll. I need to take the point that is closest to it (by using the usual distance formula `sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2)`)

This also can be done when looping, but if someone has any suggestions for better methods, I would appreciate it.

Thanks a lot for any help

Comment: Note that calling STL algorithms does not eliminate looping, it just hides them behind an abstraction layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `std::sort` on `vectorAll` with the `Compare` function designed to take into account the contents of `vectorSpecial`:

```
struct myCompareStruct
{
    std::vector<Point2f> all;
    std::vector<Point2f> special;
    myCompareStruct(const std::vector<Point2f>& a, const std::vector<Point2f>& s)
        : all(a), special(s) 
    {
    }
    bool operator() (const Point2f& i, const Point2f& j) 
    { 
        //whatever the logic is
    }
};

std::vector<Point2f> all;
std::vector<Point2f> special;
//fill your vectors
myCompareStruct compareObject(all,special);

std::sort(special.begin(),special.end(),compareObject);
```

Comment: It seems like this is what I need. but there are 2 things: 1) in the operator function it take as an input 2 Points and I compare their x and y? 2) I need to sort the "special" vector and not the "all" so do I sort it by calling `std::sort(special.begin(),special.end(),compareObject);`? I am not very experienced in C++ thank you for answering

Comment: @Youssef ok. Then your operator should take 2 points as parameters, not int's - this was just an example. For the second question, yes, I thought you wanted to sort all. Will edit.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, can the input of the operator be of different types? so Point2f and Point3f? With logic and other inputs to match?

Comment: Yes, but you cant have a container with different types.

Answer (score 0):

For your **First Step**, you can use C++11 lambda's to great effect (special.size() = K, and all.size() = N)

```
#include <algorithm>   // std::sort, std::transform, std::find, std::min_element
#include <iterator>    // std::distance

std::vector<int> indices;
indices.reserve(special.size());

// locate exact index in all for every element of special. Complexity = O(K * N)
std::transform(special.begin(), special.end(), indices.begin(), [&all](Point2f const& s){                   
     return std::distance(
         all.begin(), 
         std::find(all.begin(), all.end(), s)
     ); 
});

// sort special based on index comparison. Complexity = O(K * log(K))
std::sort(special.begin(), special.end(), [&indices](Point2f const& r, Point2f const& s){
     auto i = std::distance(special.begin(), r);
     auto j = std::distance(special.begin(), s);
     return indices[i] < indices[j];
});
```

**Explanation**: first, for every point in `special`, compute the distance between the beginning of `all` and the location of the special element in `all`, and store that result into the `indices` vector. Second, sort all elements of `special` by comparing for every pair of element the corresponding elements in the `indices` vector.

For your **Second Step**, you only have to change the way you compute indices

```
// locate closest element in all for every element of special. Complexity = O(K * N)
std::transform(special.begin(), special.end(), indices.begin(), [&all](Point2f const& s){                   
     return std::distance(
         all.begin(), 
         std::min_element(all.begin(), all.end(), [&s](Point2f const& a){
              return // Euclidean 2D-distance between a and s    
         });
     ); 
});
```

**Explanation**: the only change compared to your First Step is that for every element in `special` you find the element in `all` that is closest to it, which you do by computing the minimum Euclidean distance as you suggested in your question.

**UPDATE**: You could make a space/time tradeoff by first storing the index of every element of `all` into a `std::unordered_map` hash table, and then doing the comparison between elements of `special` based on lookup into that hash table. This reduces the time complexity of the first step to O(N) (assuming K < N), but adds O(N) of storage for the hash table.