# sort 2d vector based on another 2d vector

Tags: c++, sorting, stl, vector

So I have two 2d vectors where vector1 has the common values in the first row and vector2 has the common values in the second column. I want to sort the rows in vector2 according to the values in the first row of vector1.  Whats the best way to do this?

This is what I got so far, though I wonder if there is some way to do this better with the sort algorithm:

```
for(unsigned int i = 1; i < vec2.size(); i++)
    if(vec2[i][1] != vec1[0][i])
        swap(vec2[i], vec2[i + 1]);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/11341498/819272

Comment: A couple of questions (unrelated to your problem but still important): Why not start looping at `0`? Have you made sure that the size of `vec2` and `vec1[0]` is the same? Have you made sure that the size of `etf_comp` is one larger than the size of `vec2`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Wasn't starting the loop at 0 to skip headers.  Fixed the above code, forgot to change etf_comp to vec2.

Comment: So you explored `<algorithm>` and found `std::swap`... Why didn't you use `std::sort` from the same header while you were at it rather than invent your own [bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)? std::sort is `O(N log N)` vs `O(N^2)` for bubble sort.

Comment: @smocking Yea I said that there is probably some way to do it with sort but I haven't faintest idea the syntax for that.

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward solution could be:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> v1 = {
    { 3, 6, 4 },
    { 1, 1, 1 },
    { 1, 1, 1 }
};
std::vector<std::vector<int>> v2 = {
    { 1, 4, 1 },
    { 1, 6, 1 },
    { 1, 3, 1 }
};

const std::vector<int>& order = v1[0];

std::sort(v2.begin(), v2.end(), [&order](
    const std::vector<int>& r1, const std::vector<int>& r2) {
        auto it1 = std::find(order.begin(), order.end(), r1[1]);
        auto it2 = std::find(order.begin(), order.end(), r2[1]);
        return (it1 - it2) < 0;
});
```

However, this solution has quite a high cost, O(N^2 log N). Depending on the size of the vectors this might be a problem or not.

Another approach would be to use an intermediate vector as an indirection:

```
std::vector<int> idxs(order.size());
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < order.size(); i++)
    idxs[i] = std::find(order.begin(), order.end(), v2[i][1]) - order.begin();

// After computing the intermediate vector you could access v2 like this:
v2[idxs[i]][j]
```

This solution has O(N^2) cost, at the expense of some overhead every time you access `v2`.

Finally, you could try to come up with a custom sort solution. Still, I believe it is not possible to solve this problem with a smaller cost than O(N^2).

Comment: Thanks beta, could explain in more lay terms what you're doing in the first one?  Also for the second solution, wouldn't the idxs[i] = find(order.begin(), order.end(), **v1**) - order.begin(); ?

Comment: @riotburn You are right about `v1`. I will fix that. The first approach uses `sort` function. That function can use a compare function (in this case I used a C++11 lambda function) for comparing two elements. The compare function finds where the elements are in the first row of `v1` and based on that the whole `v2` is sorted. In order to better understand how `sort` works, have a look at [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) and try to think of an easier problem.

Comment: @riotburn For instance, you could think how you would sort a vector of strings based on the length of the strings. In that case the lambda function would be: `[](const string& s1, const string& s2) { return s1.size() < s2.size(); }`.

Comment: @riotburn Actually `find(order.begin(), order.end(), v2[i][1])` is fine, since it is looking for an element from `v2` in `order` (which is the first row of `v1`).