# Order a vector of points based on another vector of different size and type

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

To further this question: [order a vector of points based on another vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11341498/order-a-vector-of-points-based-on-another-vector), but both vectors have different types.

I'm trying to order vector with type struct Item based on another vector of type std::string. To do this, I"m using one element of the struct Item (ID of type std::string), and comparing that to a vector of strings.

```
struct myCompareStruct
{
    std::vector<std::string> all;
    std::vector<item> special;
    myCompareStruct(const std::vector<std::string>& a, const std::vector<item>& s)
        : all(a), special(s) 
    {
    }
    bool operator() (const std::string& i, const item& j) 
    { 
        return(i.compare(j.ID) == 0);
    }
};

std::vector<std::string> all;
std::vector<item> special;

//fill your vectors
myCompareStruct compareObject(all,special);
std::sort(special.begin(), special.end(), compareObject);
```

But this gives me a compile time error of: 
error C2664: 'bool myCompareStruct::operator ()(const item&,const std::string &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'item' to 'const std::string &'

item.ID is of type std::string.

Comment: Clearly your `bool operator() (const std::string& i, const item& j)` 's first argument is wrong. Tell  what is `i` ?

Comment: Are you trying to order `vector special` in a way when `item.ID` have the same orded that strings in vector `all`? If that so, has `vector all` all currently existing `item.ID` ?

Comment: vector all is just a vector of some strings. A subset is created, vector special which is a structure. More struct info is added to vector special. But I need vector special to be based on the same order as vector all. To compare them, I'm using one element of vector special, ID, which is std::string.

Comment: But you didn't answer. Anyway if I understand correctly your compare function `bool operator() (const item& i, const item& j) { return std::find(all.begin(), all.end(), i.ID) < std::find(all.begin(), all.end(), j.ID); }`

Answer (score 1):

You are sorting a `std::vector<item>` of `item` but your predicate `myCompareStruct::operator()` cannot compare two `item`s, it compares a `std::string` and an `item`. You need to write an operator like this

```
bool operator() (const item& x, const item& y) {
    return x.ID.compare(y.ID)
}
```

In order to use it in `std::sort`.
Alternativaly, if all your items can be converted to strings you may want to define a conversion from `item` to `std::string` as such

```
item::operator std::string() const {return ID}
```

Comment: k, I understand your point, but I'm trying to sort a vector of structs by one of its elements based on a vector of strings.

Comment: With the information you gave is very difficult to tell what is extacly what you are trying to do. If you post more code and what is what you want to get we might be able to help you

Comment: I'm not what more I can show. Basically, I'm trying to order one vector based on another vector. The condition compares two strings. But one string is in the element of a struct. A struct is in a vector and the vector that the sort should be based on is another vector of strings.

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't show your definitions for `i`, `item`

So, *probably* you need this :

```
 bool operator() (const std::item& i, const item& j) 
    { 
        size_t pos1 = std::find(special.begin(), special.end(),i) - special.begin() ;
        size_t pos2 = std::find(special.begin(), special.end(),j) - special.begin() ;

        return all[pos1] < all[pos2] ;
    }
```

Overload `==` for item

This can sort `special` based on exact number of elements in `all` . If this is not the case you're having a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/232397)

Comment: I'm trying to sort a vector of structs, using one of the struct elements (that's of type std::string), based on a vector of type std::string.

Comment: @user1007692 So do you care to show, what's the data members in your struct `item` ?

Comment: Well the only one relevant is Item.ID. That's what I'm using to compare with the other vector. Item.ID is a std::string.

Comment: @user1007692 you're not helping, anyway updated with whatever is mentioned in post as of now

Comment: @user1007692 Also are you aware that for sorting you need to compare two elements from same data structure ? If yes, tell how you want to compare `i` and `j` from `special` with an element from `all` in operator `()`. Simple words given `a.ID` and `b.ID` compare them with another `ID`, return 0,1,-1

Comment: if vector all is a vector of strings, and vector special is a vector of struct Items, and struct Items has ID. ID is a string. I'm trying to compare that ID (of type string) with the other string.